# Photoshop action to export png using filename pattern (@2x)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, actions, iphone

How do you create a Photoshop action to do the following:

1. Save for Web, at full size, using the (PSD) filename with "@2x" appended (and .png)
2. Save for Web, at 50% size, using the (PSD) filename (and .png)

So, if you are editing myImage.psd; you should end up with

- myImage.png (50% size)
- myImage@2x.png (100% size)

Apologies if this question is amazingly simple or has been answered elsewhere, but I have yet to find a straightforward answer explains how to export to png using the iOS naming convention.

Thanks.

Comment: For mac users: http://macrabbit.com/slicy/ -- From the http://macrabbit.com/slicy/help/ you can download example psd that has couple examples on how to make the retina files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These guys made a great [action set](http://uncorkedstudios.com/2013/01/19/best-photoshop-export-action-ever/) that does pretty much what you want.

I modified their version of the actions (JLRetinaPNGExport.atn) which you can find [here](http://www.filedropper.com/jlretinapngexport). This action set comes with 2 actions:

1. current layer export as .png at 100% then 50%
2. merge visible and export as .png at 100% then 50%

Hope this helps

Comment: This action not save automatically names. It will be great to make auto saving @2x postfix. Is it possible to be done?